# Is http_build_query() a safe way to transmit data to jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using something similar to the following script to generate an unordered list of users:

```
<?php

  $user_info = array(
    'name' => 'Curtis',
    'advisory' => 7,
    'color' => 'red'
  );
  $users = array($user_info);
  // Assume $users could have multiple user arrays in it
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    $name = $user['name'];
    $data = http_build_query($user);
    echo "<li data='$data'>$name</li>";
  }

?>
```

Here, all of the user's information is encoded as an HTML attribute, `data`. The idea for doing this is that on the front end, there is a jQuery function that, when a user is clicked on, one can edit that users info, right down to their name, color etc. This information is then sent back to the server using jQuery's `$.ajax()`.

I want to keep the info in an `<ul>` and not a `<table>` because I don't need to have the color or advisory displayed, hence using an HTML attribute to store the data. My question is this: is this a safe way of transmitting the data, considering there is back-end verification on the data it receives through `$.ajax()`? I understand there can be issues with special characters, but only integers and simple strings will be used. If not, is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You might consider loading sensitive data via AJAX only upon request, e.g. when the user clicks to edit info.

Comment: Don't parse if you don't have to. `<li data-name="$name" data-advisory="$advisory" data-color="$color">`. Then you can reference individual values via jQuery's `.data()` function.

Comment: The reason I am not using a data-id attr and then making the AJAX request off that is primarily speed concerns. The reason I am parsing it is because the script will have multiple uses, so the number of data attributes could vary. Hence they're all parses into `data`

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't and it's not what this function should be used for. http_build_query only encodes the strings for URL it doesn't give you the protection at all.

If you want to pass variables to javascript without using ajax then pass them as JSON.

```
$users = array($user_info);

echo '<script>';
echo 'var users=JSON.parse(' . json_encode($users) . ');';
echo '</script>';
```

this isn't a perfect solution because you'll mix JS and php but you get the javascript object so you can easily use it in javacsript with users[0].name; etc. or loop over the users if they're in an array

the second option is to use 'data-' and use it in `<li>` tag like `echo '<li data-user-name="' . $user['name'] . '">'` etc.

the third one commonly used is to use ajax request to get the json object returned as php script response.

If you want to be safe then you should sanitize, validate and escape user data.